# REST API call blocked for 15 minutes

Tags: soql, rest-api

I am testing Salesforce REST API calls in JMeter. Sometimes near the end of the test, one of the call is blocked for 15 minutes and no other calls work at the mean time. I notice that the one got blocked is a SOQL call:

```
https://na6.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/query?
q=SELECT+id+,+name+from+College_University__c
```

Is there a SOQL query limit that will block the call for 15 minutes?

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked" ? Any error messages?

Comment: Usually that call takes about 1 second to receive response but when it is blocked the response was returned after 15 minutes late. No error was returned.

Comment: It is hard to believe that salesforce returns data in 15 minutes. Are you sure that it is not a proxy server delay or anything else?

Comment: It could be, our network team is also investigating this issue. One thing they found out is ehe netstat -tpanel --ip command shows the data sent to Salesforce has Send-Q count in one the entry reached and remained at 495 during the ~15 minute API delay.

Comment: I have a similar problem. For weeks using the Sandbox, SOQL queries and single sobject retrieval through the REST API returned results within a few seconds. After a query returned 78K rows, suddenly all subsequent data requests for the past two weeks do not return (even single sobject retrieval and limit SOQL's). Requests to /services/data and /services/data/v45.0/sobjects/ (metadata info) return in seconds. Everything else blocks. API usage for the past 24 hours show 6 API requests (out of 5M limit)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a network admin, but from [Why does data sit in Send-Q? TCP sessions freezing](https://serverfault.com/q/740642/25048) it sounds like Salesforce wasn't acknowledging the API request.

I suspect this is related to the [API Request Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm). In particular, those for concurrent API requests. If JMeter is attempting to load up the concurrent API calls you could be getting throttled if they start to exceed 20 seconds individually. However, I'd expect this to result in a `ConcurrentPerOrgApex Limit exceeded` response.

If not that specific limit, you've instead tripped something else that is preventing you from making a large number of API calls to your Salesforce org.